# Split hex string into 4 byte in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, hex

I have a dataframe like this:

```
idx  cola  colb  hexstring
0      2     a   2000001443b660280c25800380241c0000102000120000000000000000000003010
1      3     b   80b7d0082b7d0082b7d00821d640000102000
2      5     a   ffffffff34140038030000014
...
```

And I want to split the hexstring column with 4 byte, and fill with the rest with 0, such that,

```
idx  cola  colb  hexstring
0      2     a   00003010
0      2     a   00000000
0      2     a   00000000
0      2     a   02000120
0      2     a   41c00001
0      2     a   58003802
0      2     a   660280c2
0      2     a   0001443b
0      2     a   00000200
1      3     b   00102000
1      3     b   821d6400
1      3     b   0082b7d0
1      3     b   082b7d00
...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not particularly aware of bytes and such, but here my solution will get you to your destination. From what I understand is you want to split your string into pieces of 8 characters from the back. But if the initial chracters will not have 8 enough, you want to add zeros in front.

My solution here make your strings into times of eight first by adding zeros in front.

```
import pandas as pd
import math

df= pd.DataFrame({"idx  ":[0,1,2],
                  "cola" : [2,3,5],
                  "colb" : ["a","b","a"],
                  "hexstring": ["2000001443b660280c25800380241c0000102000120000000000000000000003010", "80b7d0082b7d0082b7d00821d640000102000", "ffffffff34140038030000014"]})

df["hexstring"]
0    2000001443b660280c25800380241c0000102000120000...
1                80b7d0082b7d0082b7d00821d640000102000
2                            ffffffff34140038030000014
Name: hexstring, dtype: object

df["hexstring"] = df["hexstring"].apply(lambda x: x.zfill((math.ceil(len(x)/8))*8))
0    000002000001443b660280c25800380241c00001020001...
1             00080b7d0082b7d0082b7d00821d640000102000
2                     0000000ffffffff34140038030000014
Name: hexstring, dtype: object
```

zfill adds zeros in front of the string for the specified amount. For the amount, I calculate by dividing the length of the string wih 8 and getting the nearest higher integer. Now you have all strings in times of 8.

```
df["hexstring"] = df["hexstring"].apply(lambda x: [x[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(x), 8)])

df["hexstring"]
0    [00000200, 0001443b, 660280c2, 58003802, 41c00...
1    [00080b7d, 0082b7d0, 082b7d00, 821d6400, 00102...
2             [0000000f, fffffff3, 41400380, 30000014]
Name: hexstring, dtype: object

df = df.explode('hexstring')
   idx    cola colb hexstring
0      0     2    a  00000200
0      0     2    a  0001443b
0      0     2    a  660280c2
0      0     2    a  58003802
0      0     2    a  41c00001
0      0     2    a  02000120
0      0     2    a  00000000
0      0     2    a  00000000
0      0     2    a  00003010
1      1     3    b  00080b7d
1      1     3    b  0082b7d0
1      1     3    b  082b7d00
1      1     3    b  821d6400
1      1     3    b  00102000
2      2     5    a  0000000f
2      2     5    a  fffffff3
2      2     5    a  41400380
2      2     5    a  30000014
```

Then I split the string into groups of eights and keep it in a list. Afterwards you can just explode the lists so that you can get each groups in seperate rows.
Of course, here the results are the reverse of what you want because the lists explode from the beginning. If you prefer your exact target, you can reverse the lists before exploding them.

```
df["hexstring"] = df["hexstring"].apply(lambda x: [x[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(x), 8)][::-1]) #[::-1] reverse the list
0    [00003010, 00000000, 00000000, 02000120, 41c00...
1    [00102000, 821d6400, 082b7d00, 0082b7d0, 00080...
2             [30000014, 41400380, fffffff3, 0000000f]

df = df.explode('hexstring')
   idx    cola colb hexstring
0      0     2    a  00003010
0      0     2    a  00000000
0      0     2    a  00000000
0      0     2    a  02000120
0      0     2    a  41c00001
0      0     2    a  58003802
0      0     2    a  660280c2
0      0     2    a  0001443b
0      0     2    a  00000200
1      1     3    b  00102000
1      1     3    b  821d6400
1      1     3    b  082b7d00
1      1     3    b  0082b7d0
1      1     3    b  00080b7d
2      2     5    a  30000014
2      2     5    a  41400380
2      2     5    a  fffffff3
2      2     5    a  0000000f
```

Comment: This really helps! Brilliant!